# How to implement Staggered GridView with Sections?

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

I just want to implement **sections** in **Staggered GridView.** such as Today, Yesterday and Other. 
I have tried with below libraries but I have no luck.

1. [Staggered GridView](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid)
2. RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager.

Can you give any suggestion on how to implement this ?

Comment: Specify what problem you are facing or what you want to achieve with some code or screenshot.

Comment: If you have tried then post those code and mention issues/details!

Comment: Issue is alreday raised in https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid/issues/166

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented this by using RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManger in **SimpleAdapter.java**.

```
      if (position % 5 == 0) {
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
        } else {
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.setFullSpan(false);
        }
```

Here is the link I have created a demo for this [**StaggeredGridViewSections**](https://github.com/rameshkec85/StaggeredGridViewSections)

Answer (score 1):

You can use StaggeredGridLayoutManager with a custom ItemDecoration.

Here's a library that does that with LinearLayoutManager,
[sticky-headers-recyclerview](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview). You might be able to tweak it for your needs or at least have an idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need RecycleView, that is another option: https://github.com/sarahlensing/StaggeredGridView

Answer (score 0):

You can use StaggeredGridLayoutManager with one adapter and set two ItemViewTypes
and for the section view set full span to true.

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
```